# SQLServer the port number is not valid

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-8.2

Estoy recibiendo un mensaje de error al intentar conectar Java con SqlServer, el error que 
me envia es que el puerto 1433 es invalido para mi base de datos.
Ya habilite el puerto 1433 de entrada y salida para SQLServer al igaul tengo agregado el driver a mi proyecto, no se que mas pueda estarme dando este error. Este es mi codigo:

```
package CDatabase;
```

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author JDanielSolisV
 */
public class Conexion {
    /**Agregamos las clases como privadas y estaticas para que no sean llamadas desde otras clases*/
    private static String driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private static String db="SysInventory";
    private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433" + db; 
    private static String user="xxxx";
    private static String pass="xxxx";

```
public static Connection getConnection(){
    Connection link=null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        link = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        link.setAutoCommit(false);
        if (link !=null) {
            System.out.println("Conexion exitosa!!!!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Conexion erronea");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion erronea" + e.getMessage());
    } 
    return link;
}

public void desconexion(){
    Connection link=null;
    try {
        link.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error al desconectar" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Conexion c = new Conexion();
    c.getConnection();
}
```

}

Aqui el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Verifica si la BD está corriendo en el puerto `1433` o en otro puerto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, al concatenar las variables, estás dejando tu basededatos sin separar del puerto de conexión:

```
private static String db  = "SysInventory";
private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433" + db
```

Te quedaría como URL de conexión:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433SysInventory.
```

El formato de la URL de conexión para SQL Server es el siguiente:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

Que en tu caso, sería:

```
private static String db  = "SysInventory";
private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=" + db;
```

Referencias:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15